# cross-platform method for determining file owner in Python

Tags: python, cross-platform, python-module

I need to find the owner of files in a script running on Windows, Linux and Mac. `os.stat` returns the owner id, but on windows I can't use `getpwuid` to find the actual name of the owner. I need the name as a string.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you won't find a silver bullet (cross platform). For windows you can use the win32 module like shown [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-the-owner-of-a-file.html)

```
import win32api
import win32con
import win32security

FILENAME = "temp.txt"
open (FILENAME, "w").close ()

print "I am", win32api.GetUserNameEx (win32con.NameSamCompatible)

sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity (FILENAME, win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
owner_sid = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner ()
name, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountSid (None, owner_sid)

print "File owned by %s\\%s" % (domain, name)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of opening the file for writing?

Comment: It is for the sake of the example only (to make sure the example can run with a file that already exists). Then it gets the domain and name from that file.